# What is 'slave to the grind' meaning in skid row's album?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

What is `slave to the grind` means?
it's the album title of skid row

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about interpreting a one-off artistic/poetic usage in an album title. Presumably ***grind*** here primarily alludes to heavy metal subgenres like [*death-grind, pornogrind, grindcore, noisegrind*,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deathgrind) etc. But that's all domain-specific terminology which I don't pretend to understand. It's *popular music*, not English.

Comment: Slave to the grind, as in the grind of working, seems reasonable to me without music-specific terminology.  Google "the daily grind" for example.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because a literal interpretation wouldn't completely and accurately answer the question and an analysis of any double entendre would be both opinion based and probably more of a discussion than an answer unless Skid Row decides to drop in and explain what they meant.

Comment: The question `What does slave to the grind mean?` is a valid question, correct?  It's just the music reference that you object to?  I think that's a reasonably answerable question and if the music reference is the problem, just remove it (or make it clear it's just a bit of background information and the question isn't asking for interpretation of lyrics).

Comment: For me, it is not so much the "music reference." There is no "music reference" except that it is the name of an album. As such there is next to no context from which to interpret the sentence. We often ask for more context when we get questions about a single sentence. In this case, it is not possible.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about interpreting the title of a record album and no further context is available to allow anything but guessing as to the meaning of the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

"Grind" likely means in this context the "daily grind", or the routine of going to work every day.  [This ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41272/meaning-and-origin-of-the-grind-of-my-day) for example explains this in a bit more detail.

From that question, and from there from [dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/daily+grind):

> daily grind
> (noun)
>
> > everyday routine, esp. monotonous
>
> Examples
>
> > The daily grind was starting to get to her.

So here, Skid Row is referring to being a slave to the daily work routine - either objecting to the fact that you *must* perform this routine in order to survive, or the fact that once you get in a routine the routine will often control you.

Comment: And you're completely certain that they weren't alluding to a secondary meaning, like the slang "grind" for ["An erotic rotation of the pelvis"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/grind), or "grindcore" heavy metal genre that preceded the band? Heavy metal in general is full of double entendre.

Comment: @ColleenV: That's another possibility, but given the band is *Skid Row* it's much more likely to be primarily referencing [*grinding overdriven bass*](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=7KlbVM6gCM3H8gfdxYCAAg&gws_rd=ssl#q=heavy+metal+grinding+bass), or on that same page *the fact that **grind** is a British term for **thrash** [metal music]*. I kinda doubt the members of Skid Row know or care much about the daily grind of a 9-5 job.

Comment: @FumbleFingers that's exactly why I agreed with your close vote. Either the question can be answered with a dictionary or it's subject to a variety of interpretations. There's no correct answer here unless the band has already explained it.

Comment: @ColleenV: Absolutely. If OP had asked the meaning of [*daily grind*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/daily+grind) it would presumably have been GR. I'm not sure how I'd closevote a question asking what [*Slave to Love*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slave_to_Love) means, but I'd certainly hope to find a justifiable reason. This sort of thing just doesn't seem appropriate for ELL.

Comment: Who knows if they meant the double entendre.  However, *slave to the grind* has a very straightforward meaning, and given this is ELL it seems like the right one to teach.  Certainly the frustration of having to work is a common topic of songs.  Additionally, look at the lyrics: there are several references in it to "punch the clock" and such, which is similarly clearly a reference to work.

Comment: If the question had been asked because the poster had looked up the individual words and it didn't make sense, I would say it's on-topic. However, if the only meaning is the straightforward one, it's off-topic as completely answerable with a dictionary. [slave to idiom](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/slave+to) and [grind definition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/grind).

Comment: @ColleenV let's just be open minded. of course it's suitable for ELL. It can be one of example about how we use word 'grind'.

Comment: @stormrage - Maybe if the question were edited to include more detail and the research the asker did to try to answer their question. The site isn't supposed to be a substitute for an online dictionary. If the question is really deeper than "tell me the meaning because I'm too lazy to go look it up", it should be edited to reflect that so that we can focus our explanations on which part is confusing to the asker. The system flagged this question as "low quality" for a reason.

Comment: The system flagged it low quality because it's short.  Whether that's a problem in this specific case is a separate issue...

Comment: It was flagged because questions and answers this short rarely have enough detail to make them worth keeping around. The goal as I understand it is to build a library of questions and answers that is useful to many people over time, not to answer specific questions. The "How do I ask a good question?" section in the help covers both "search for an answer before asking" and "make it relevant to others". This question is not a good question as it is stated. I do think it is possible to make it into a good question with some explanation of why a simple search didn't return a useful answer.

Comment: Your answer is a complete guess. And I don't support supplying any alleged literal meaning as appropriate for a question that asks not about the literal meaning, but about the meaning. In a one-sentence context, it could mean a multitude of things, or have an esoteric meaning. There is a title track, but then you get into interpretation of lyrics. And the OP does not even ask about the song, apparently.